# Highly-voted comments have less contrast than low vote ones

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

The current CSS rules for the main site have highly-voted comments appearing in grey, while low-vote comments are displaying in bright red:

> [image]

Not sure what the standard is, but I'm pretty sure that's not how it works on SO, at least (e.g., see the comments on [this random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908/168775)). Can we have something similar here? It just seems visually off.

Comment: Yes, this bothers me too. The "cool" comments are gray, the "warm" and "hot" comments are red, and then the "supernova" comments are gray again.

Comment: This looks like it [still hasn't been addressed](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16367/why-do-american-colleges-and-universities-have-sports-teams); any comment from the community mod team?